# How do I push a wallpaper to android?

Tags: android

I am in an operating systems course that centers around hacking up android phones. I want to set my friend's wallpaper to something amusing but benign. Sadly, our test phones does not have wireless drivers on them. Any idea of how I can adb push something in?

Is there a wallpapers directory I can place things in, for instance?

Comment: What exactly are they teaching you to hack in android such that figuring out how to change the wallpaper is more difficult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place it on the phones external storage:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

or you could create your own directory on the external storage:

```
                File root = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "MyAppName" + File.separator);
                root.mkdirs();
```